# Calling a virtual member function from inside the (template) base class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, polymorphism

Suppose I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        T t = get();
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    virtual T get() const
    {
        // assumes T can be constructed from, say, -1
        T t = -1.0;
        return t;
    }
};

class derived : public base<std::string>
{
public:
    virtual std::string get() const
    {
        // this is a silly example, but one can
        // imagine that what we return here could
        // depend on data members of derived
        return "this is a string";
    }
};

int main()
{
    derived d;
    d.print();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that `d.print()` should call `derived::get()` because `get()` is virtual. However, I'm getting a compiler error saying that I can't initialize a `string` to `-1.0`, which means that the compiler is trying to call `base::get()` when I call `d.print()`. What's going on?

Comment: This code does not compile, because `print` is private. Please post code you have tested and are sure that it exposes the problem.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: The compiler doesn't generally get that far (or at least, not without prior errors), because the problem happens when he tries to instantiate `base<std::string>`.

Comment: @NicolBolas You misunderstood his comment. The example does not compile without fixes here and there

Comment: @VJo You misunderstood his comment :). It implies, that OP posted exactly the code that he got error on

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Those members should are meant to be public (I've edited the code in the question), and it is when they are public that I get the error.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Common, it is trivial to fix the access specifier there. Give the guy some slack... There is a huge difference from just missing an access specifier while copying and creating an example that will not compile for many different reasons, and it is clear that the error he is getting is unrelated to the access specifier...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Fair point. I fixed the other errors myself. So many people here forget to post useful examples, I may have gone over the top here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, I'm getting a compiler error saying that I can't initialize a string to -1.0, which means that the compiler is trying to call base::get() when I call d.print().

No, that compiler error means that the compiler is trying to instantiate `base<std::string>::get()`, which it *must* do because `derived` uses `base<std::string>` as a base class. Just because you don't call a function doesn't mean you *can't*. You could still call `base<std::string>::get()` directly.

You instantiated `base<std::string>` and used it as a base class. Since `base<std::string>::get()` is a virtual function, it is considered "used" by the fact that you use `base<std::string>` as a base class. Since it is in use, it must be instantiated. So the compiler must and will attempt to compile the function.

And since `std::string` cannot be implicitly constructed from a float, the compiler errors out from a failed template substitution.

Comment: @commernie: Nicol is right. You can even comment out `d.print()` and you'll get the same error (probably you'll have to disable optimizations)

Comment: Thanks Nicol! Of course you are correct; can't believe I was being so silly.

Comment: *Instantiating `base<std::string>` means instantiating its members too*. This is not true. *Explicit instantiation* will instantiate all members, *implicit instantiation* (as is the case here) will only instantiate those members that are *used* according to the definition of *use* in §3.2.

Comment: @commernie: You have accepted an answer that is *wrong*, until the answer is corrected I would reconsider the *acceptance*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Partially wrong. The idea is still correct, as is the way to correct it.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The statement is wrong, and anyone that comes and sees the answer will "understand" that all member functions are implicitly instantiated, and that is false, and trivial to demonstrate. The first line of the answer and the last paragraph are correct, everything else is not and only adds noise. Consider this: `template <typename T> struct base { T get() { T = -1; } }; struct der : base<string> { string get() { return ""; } };` Why does this other piece of code compile? According to your answer it shouldn't, because it should instantiate `base<string>::get()` and that cannot compile

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: initializing t to T() (instead of -1.0) in base::get got rid of the error, which seems to suggest Nicol's answer is correct. If a better answer comes along I will un-accept this one.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant. If Nicol edits his answer would be appropriate to accept it? (I'm new around here.)

Comment: @commernie: If the answer is edited and after the edit is correct, then it is perfectly fine to accept it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Here's a question. This is Stack Overflow. You have 45+k rep. In the time it has taken you to type these comments in, **you** could have corrected it. So why did you bother even making the comment, when you could have just gone in and fixed it yourself? In any case, I have since corrected it.

Comment: @Nicol: I think, he didn't correct it himself, because it is a major change in your post and the logic of your answer depends on that change. Typos can be corrected by others without hesitation, not "claims".

Comment: @NicolBolas: As I understand the rules, editing another person's question or answer should not be done to change the meaning, but rather to fix issues like spelling, formatting and the like. Yes, I can edit the question, but I don't feel comfortable changing what you intended to say. I posted the comment because I think that it is important both for you, for the person that asked and for anyone that comes later to know that as it was, the answer was incorrect. I am removing my downvote now.

Comment: @Nawaz: But it isn't a major change. The problem is that `base::get` is being instantiated. The reason _why_ it was being instantiated is what needed to be changed. As my correction points out.

Comment: @Nicol: As I see it, it is a major change, because the logic of your answer, depends on that.

Comment: With regards to @DavidRodríguez-dribeas comments: an important point which David neglected to mention (except indirectly) is that a virtual function is considered used if an object of that type (or a type derived from it) is instantiated.  (The motive for this: the compiler must put its address in the vtable.)  So while his comments concerning the error in the original answer are correct, quick tests suppressing the problem line in the function may be misleading; the function in the base class is considered "used", even if it will never be called in actual execution.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for the info. You guys are ridiculously knowledgeable.

Answer (score 4):

When you implicitly instantiate a class template, only those member functions that are *used* will be instantiated, as you already know or else you would not be asking this. The problem is that the definition of *use* in the standard may not be exactly what you expect, and in particular, any *virtual* function is *used* if it is not *pure*

> §3.2p2 [...]A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure.[...]

And this means that `base::get` is used even if your code does not explicitly call it, and thus the compiler will implicitly instantiate it and trigger the compiler error that you are seeing.

Comment: Would making it non-virtual fix this?

Comment: @commernie: You can fix it in different ways, if you make it non-virtual then it will compile, but at the same time, you cannot use it polymorphically through a reference to `base<std::string>`, that is, you will make it compile but will change the semantics. Alternatively you can fix the code so that even if it is instantiated it won't break (change initialization) or make the function pure (this again will change the semantics of the code) Deciding among the different options has to be done in the context of the problem to solve.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks for your answers. I understand perfectly. In retrospect, even my initial question seems rather silly. Anyway, I've found a way to fix it that I'm happy with and that gives me the desired behavior. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
T t = -1.0;
```

Of course, this wouldn't compile if `T` is `std::string`. It has nothing to do with `get` being `virtual` and which function will be called at runtime. Runtime comes after code gets compiled to machine code, and your code wouldn't even compile.

Why don't you do this:

```
T t = T();
```

Again it requires `T` to have a default constructor.

Comment: Indeed. The change I have in mind is in the vein of what you suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this method (where T=std::string) :

```
virtual T get() const
{
    // assumes T can be constructed from, say, -1
    T t = -1.0;
    return t;
}
```

The compiler is right. You can not initialize std::string using a double value.